# How to Omit NaN values when applying groupyby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset consisting of multiple columns and I want to calculate the average by using the `groupby` function in Python. However, since some of the values are `NAN` I get that the mean of that particular group is `NAN` when a `NAN` value is present. I would like to omit this value, not set it to zero or fill it with any statistical variable, just omit.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that by default the mean method ignores the NaN. Please post your code.

Comment: I suspect your `NAN` are strings.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, in a previous calculation I am forcing NA values with this `pd.np.nan`. Probably this is not the way to do it. How do I enforce NAN values?

Answer (score 1):

The NaN are ignored by the `mean` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [3., 4., np.nan, 5.]}) 
#    a   b
# 0  1   3
# 1  1   4
# 2  2 NaN
# 3  2   5

df.groupby('a').mean()
#      b
# a     
# 1  3.5
# 2  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get that the mean of that particular group is NAN when a NAN value
>   is present

FALSE! :)

the mean will only consider non null values. You are safe my man.